# 'mtry' in 'rfcv()' function of R's 'randomForest' library

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, random-forest, cross-validation

I would like to use cross validation to determine the number of variables to try in a Random Forest method. I don't understand how to use the `mtry` argument in the `rfcv()` function.

I have 6 predictors in my dataset. I want to use `mtry = 6,5,4,3,2,1`, e.g., any possible m value, and cross validate with 5-fold CV.

I believe this can be done with `rfcv()` function of `randomForest` package. I am running the code:

`rf_cv<- rfcv(training_x,training_y,cv.fold=5, mtry=function(p) max(1, p-1))`

However, calling `rf_cv$n.var` gives me:
`[1] 6 3 1`

So, this method does not apply `mtry` as I was hoping, since I said each time subtract the number of variables used by 1.

How can I try every number of variables by applying a 5-fold cross validation for each number of variable?

I checked [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/233863/206540) post, however it is not completely related since they are discussing the default of `mtry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the post you referenced, it explains how the steps will determine the mtry tested. So in your case, p=6, and since you did not change step or the scale, then:

```
p=6; 0.5
k <- floor(log(p, base = 1/step))
n.var <- round(p * step^(0:(k - 1)))
[1] 6 3
```

And if n.var does not include 1, it goes ahead and includes it for you, which gives you 6,3,1. So if you want to try all numbers, set mtry to be identity, and step to be 1, set scale to anything but "log" (yeah the code doesn't give you other options):

```
rf_cv=rfcv(matrix(rnorm(100*6),ncol=6),rnorm(100),cv.fold=3,
mtry=identity,scale="new",step=-1)

rf_cv$n.var
[1] 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: I was trying the 'log' case which was again enumerating 6-5-4-3-2-1. My code was:
`rf_cv<- rfcv(training_x, training_y, cv.fold=5, scale = 'log', step = 0.9)`

But now, I get different errors with your suggestion. Both methods are enumeratig 6:1 but giving different errors. Do you think these are two different methods?

Comment: E.g., compare your code with:
`rf_cv=rfcv(matrix(rnorm(100*6),ncol=6),rnorm(100),cv.fold=3,scale = 'log', step = 0.9)`
and the rf_cv$error.cv values are different.

Comment: no, your answer is great, thanks for that. But yes, even when the seed is the same and two methods both give 6,5,...,1, still they have very different results. I don't get different results if I run the same one twice.